# no operator ">>" matches these operands operand types are: std::istream >> double*

Tags: c++, pointers, structure

I'm trying to dynamically allocate an array from a structure. I've look on a couple of other pages on stackoverflow and tried some some code, but none seems to work for my case. The closest I've found to what I'm doing is here:

[C++ dynamic memory allocation with arrays in a structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17577170/c-dynamic-memory-allocation-with-arrays-in-a-structure)

For some reason when I use this line of code:

```
cin >> testsPtr[i].students;
```

I get the error in the title. I've also tried using:

```
cin >> testsPtr[i]->students;
```

How can I have the user enter the data for my program?

Here are the specifications for the programming challenge:

Modify the program of Programming Challenge 1 to allow the user to enter name-score pairs. For each student taking a test, the user types a string representing the name of the student, followed by an integer representing the students score. Modify both the sorting and average-calculating functions so they take arrays of structures, with each structure containing the name and score of a single student. In traversing the arrays, use pointers rather than array indices.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;


int main() {

void averageScore(double*, int);
void sort(double*, int);

int numScores;

struct studentScores {
    double *scores;
    string *students;
};


cout << "How many test scores will you be entering?" << endl;
cin >> numScores;

studentScores *testsPtr = new studentScores[numScores];

for (int i = 0; i < numScores; i++) {

    cout << "What is the #" << i + 1 << " students name?" << endl;
    cin >> testsPtr[i].students;
    for (int j = 0; j < numScores; j++) {

        cout << "Please enter test score #" << j + 1 << endl;

        do {
            cin >> testsPtr[j].scores;
            if (testsPtr[i].scores < 0) {
                cout << "A test score can't be less than 0. Re-enter test score #" << i + 1 << endl;
            }

        } while (testsPtr[i].scores < 0);
    }
}

cout << endl;

/*sort(testsPtr.scores, numScores);
cout << endl;

averageScore(testScores, numScores);
cout << endl;*/
for (int i = 0; i <= numScores; i++) {
    cout << testsPtr->students << " test scores are: " << endl;
    for (int j = 0; j <= numScores; j++) {
        cout << testsPtr->scores;
    }
}

delete[] testsPtr;
testsPtr = nullptr;


return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to allocate memory for  *scores and *students. And you can't simply write cin >> testsPtr[i].students cause it means reading value for pointer not for array values

Comment: Or not make them pointers?

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<std::string> students;`?  And `std::vector<double> scores`?  And `std::vector<studentScores> testPtr(numScores)`?

Comment: This is a programming challenge from the book c++ early objects. I'm suppose to modify an older program using structures and pointers.

Comment: *This is a programming challenge from the book c++ early objects.* -- The problem with this is that hardly anyone, if anyone has read that book to know exactly what can or cannot be used.  The comments are assuming you want to use best or better practices when writing C++ code.

Comment: Does the code not show what I'm trying to do?

Comment: As I understand you have to read array of students each elements of which contains student's name and his scores? Is scores one number or set of numbers?

Comment: @KennyFreeman -- We cannot assume if the code you posted is due to having to do things this way, or just plain old not knowing about `vector`, and once known, will suffice as an answer.

Comment: You are missing `#include <string>`

Comment: @KennyFreeman -- *Modify the program of Programming Challenge 1 to allow the user to enter name-score pairs* -- Where does it say that modification rules out using `std::vector`?  Second, your current program has 3 pointers being used, but the two pointers in your class are uninitialized.  You cannot use them for anything until they point somewhere valid.

Comment: @KennyFreeman -- Also, don't you want to allocate `n` scores to go with `n` students?  That `studentScores` struct should not even be dynamically allocated, as it is just a container for the scores and students.  It's as if you are designing a parking lot to hold `n` cars, and instead of allocating space for each car, you instead allocated `n` entire parking lots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereference pointer before reading value:

```
cin >> *(testsPtr[i].students);
```

But before you have to create object `string` and reference pointer to it:

```
testsPtr[i].students = new string;
```

Comment: Thanks you, this worked. I think I need to go back through and re-read this chapter.

Answer (score 2):

The fix to your problem is to change your `cin` line to this `cin >> *(testsPtr[i].students);` this is because `testsPtr[i].students` is a pointer so you have to use the deference pointer. Make sure you correctly initialize the members.

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're trying to read value into pointer `cin >> *(testsPtr[i].students);` is the same as `cin >> testsPtr[i]->students;`. Need to allocate memory for `string* students` before reading values to `string`.

Comment: @oybek it is not. `->students` is for pointers but `testPtr` is an array furthermore the member `student` is a pointer therefore we need to deference it.

Comment: `*(testsPtr[i].students)` dereferences pointer but there are no memory allocated for it - so you'll get `Seg fault` or unpredictable behavior of program

Comment: I tried this. It allows me to enter the first student name and then it crashes.

Comment: @KennyFreeman that's because you didn't follow the advice to "correctly initialize the members". Your program has multiple bugs.